# Keepalived + Haproxy performance, apache or nginx?

Tags: cluster, haproxy, high-availability, keepalive

I have a question about Keepalived + Haproxy. At work I am assigned to deploy a redundant web server with Keepalived and Haproxy. Our setup at the moment is as follows:

Apache (as load balancer) + Modsecurity (waf) ------> 3 x IIS (Webserver, Windows Server 2012)

The issue here is, Apache is getting slower in load balancing the requests.

Should I use:

Scenario 1:

Apache and Modsecurity as ssl offload and waf.
 keepalived + haproxy for redundancy and load balancer.

Scenario 2:

Keepalived (redundancy) ----> 2 x Apache (load balancer) + Modsecurity (waf) ------> 3 x IIS

Screnario 3:

Using nginx as the SSL offload , and Modsecurity as waf + Keepalived and Haproxy.

Which is better performance wise? Thx before :)

Answer (score -1):

I have the fourth scenario with fewer layers : 
Keepalived and Haproxy ( Haproxy also works as SSL offload)   => IIS  ( IIS with WAF installed)
. I see that Modsecurity support IIS but I haven't used before. Please well-testing before applying.

In case that it's hard to install WAF in IIS due to some reasons, I prefer your Screnario 3.

Comment: why do you vote down ? I need the reason for avoiding next time. Thanks